# Azure bus service trigger function not working with my named function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I created a service bus queue azure function and I named the project PostEventEmailFunction. Then I named function and the .cs file PostEventEmail.cs which has the function named the same 'PostEventEmail' but the function doesn't get triggered by a message and I see an an error when I go to the Azure portal like this

[image]

If I remove this naming convention for the function 'PostEventEmail' and I leave the name as the default name 'Function1.cs' then it works!

Why is this?

Comment: Can you provide a github sample which can help to investigate.

Comment: Are you developing in the portal, using VS, or using the functions CLI? It looks like you are running in the portal, but in the portal you shouldn't have any .cs files. You should have a single run.csx file.